# Custom ordering of categories using WP REST API

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am using WP as my CMS and React for my web. When I add all the categories I need to WP, I fetch them and display on my React app. But the problem is that I need custom ordering, so for example, if I make categories like `Apple, Banana, Orange`, in this order, I want to receive it from API in the same order. But instead it returns in order by date or anything else, not exactly what I want.

Is there a solution to this? Or should I re-create all the categories in the order I want and then fetch them from API in ascending order by date?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle it from your `API`,  one of your ways is  to give your data (from your `wp API`),
to a [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) server ( or any other server ) and categorize and order however you want
then pass it to your `react app`.

but it gives you an additional layer, which costs more money, technology and time, so if you manipulate your data, it's better to do it in your `wp` or do it in your react app which is simpler(but you lose some features, like pagination on the server)

hope you get the idea

Comment: Maybe you know whether `wp` has this feature to add custom order?

Comment: Tell me how you send your data from wp?